# Top level window labels are not showing

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm a beginner at tkinter and oop, I wanted to create a simple multi window application that has two classes, the first has an 'Open a window' that open a Top level window with some widgets, the top level window shows but it's empty, and I got the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):File 
"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", 
line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test1\f.py", line 78, in open_window
    window = Window(self)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test1\f.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.list_box2= Listbox(Window, width='65', height='18')
  File 
"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", 
line 3191, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'listbox', cnf, kw)
  File 
"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", 
line 2595, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File 
"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", 
line 2564, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: type object 'Window' has no attribute 'tk'
```

Here is my .py file

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class Window(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.geometry('1000x600+100+50')
        self.title('Aplication Ksk')



        self.list_box2= Listbox(Window, width='65', height='18')
        self.list_box3= Listbox(Window, width='65', height='18')

        self.io_number=Label(Window, text = 'IO number: ')
        self.wo_number=Label(Window, text = 'WO: ')
        self.operator_lbl=Label(Window, text = 'Operator')
        self.sequence=Label(Window, text = 'Sequence')
        self.left_wires_names=Label(Window, text = 'Left wires')
        self.right_wires_names=Label(Window, text = 'Right wires')

        self.show_sp2=Entry(Window)
        self.show_sp1=Entry(Window)
        self.show_sequence=Entry(Window)
        self.show_io=Entry(Window)
        self.show_wo=Entry(Window)
        self.operator_=Entry(Window)

        self.btn_close = Button(Window, text="Close")
        self.btn_save = Button(Window, text="Save")
        self.btn_print = Button(Window, text="print QR code")

        #########################
        self.show_sp2.place(x=80, y=60)
        self.show_sp1.place(x= 300, y=60)
        self.show_sequence.place(x=770, y=60)
        self.sequence.place(x=770, y=35)
        self.btn_print.place(x=770, y=85)

        self.io_number.place(x=80, y=140)
        self.show_io.place(x=150, y=140)
        self.wo_number.place(x=300, y=140)
        self.show_wo.place(x=335, y=140)
        self.operator_lbl.place(x=510, y=140)
        self.operator_.place(x=570, y=140)

        self.list_box2.place(x=80, y= 220)
        self.list_box3.place(x=510, y=220)

        self.left_wires_names.place(x=257, y=195)
        self.right_wires_names.place(x=680, y=195)

        self.btn_close.place(x=257, y=530)
        self.btn_save.place(x=680, y=530)

        ttk.Button(self,
                text='Close',
                command=self.destroy).pack(expand=True)




class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('300x200')
        self.title('Main Window')

        # place a button on the root window
        ttk.Button(self,
                text='Open a window',
                command=self.open_window).pack(expand=True)

    def open_window(self):
        window = Window(self)
        window.grab_set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I want the top-level layout to show as normally should, also I want to know if I want to build a larger application, how can I access an exact input instance from another class ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Window` is a class, not a widget. You can only use widgets as parents to other widgets. Every place where you create a widget you need to pass `self` rather than `Window` as the first parameter.

```
self.list_box2= Listbox(self, width='65', height='18')
```